# Prevent window scrolling with canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I'm trying to prevent the window from scrolling when the mouse wheel is used while over a canvas. I tried disabling it like this:

```
document.getElementById( "canvasId" ).onmousedown = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
};
```

And several other ways but nothing works see:

http://jsfiddle.net/MZ9Xm/1/

Make the browser window small so there is a scroll bar, then mouse wheel over the canvas and it will make the window scroll. How can I let the canvas receive the wheel message but prevent the window from scrolling?

I'm using jquery (not shown here).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `wheel` event. You may need to use `mousewheel` instead for [other browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousewheel) than Firefox -- but please note that the `mousewheel` event has since been deprecated in favor of `WheelEvent`.

### Vanilla JavaScript version

```js
document.getElementById( "canvasId" ).onwheel = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
};

document.getElementById( "canvasId" ).onmousewheel = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
};
```

```css
html, body {height:200%} canvas {border:4px solid red}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvasId"></canvas>
```

### jQuery version

```js
$("#canvasId").bind("wheel mousewheel", function(e) {e.preventDefault()});
```

```css
html, body {height:200%} canvas {border:4px solid red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvasId"></canvas>
```

Comment: This seems to disable the canvas from receiving the wheel message as well.  From the original question "How can I let the canvas receive the wheel message but prevent the window from scrolling?"

Comment: In my case the mouse wheel is meant to zoom in/out of a graph, but I don't want it to also scroll the window up and down. That is if you are over the canvas the wheel message should be received by the canvas only, not by the whole document.

Comment: @Philip use the same event to do the zooming

Comment: Okay yes this works. At first I used two events (`"wheel mousewheel"`) in the canvas code (`mycanvas.addEventListener("wheel mousewheel"...`) and that didn't work.

Comment: @Philip can you elaborate how you achieved zooming while disabling scroll? For me it is disabling scroll but not allowing zoom

Comment: This doesn't work the page still moves if you draw with touch on the canvas, if the page is scrollable :(

Answer (score 0):

This worked quite well for me

```
document.addEventListener("mousewheel", (e)=>{
    if(e.target === htmlCanvasRef) {
        e.preventDefault()
        canvasApp.zoom(/*do smth with e*/)
        console.log('not scrolling')
    } else {
        console.log('scrolling')
    }
}, { passive: false });
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.